# How can I set a specific method of aLaravel 4 resource route in my ACL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, acl

I have a fairly simple ACL system set up. The filter checks if the user is part of a user group which has access to the route or if the user has access to the route. It works for individual routes and works for resources in general. However I want some users to have access to a specific method of a resource route, but not all of it. for example, user1 is part of the admin group and always has access to the admin resource route but user2 is not a part of the admin user group and I want to give him access to teh resource admin/create. How can I go about this in Laravel 4 with my setup

Database

```
 Routes:
      id
      route
      created_by
      last_editted_by
      created
      updated
      deleted_at

acl (table it looks at to see if user has access)
      id
      routes_id
      user_id
      group_id
      created
      updated
      deleted_at

Filter
if (Auth::check()){
    $route = Request::segment(1);

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $acl_count = Acls::join('routes','routes.id','=','acl.routes_id')
                ->where('routes.route','=',$route)
                ->Where(function($in_parenthesis) use($user_id){
                    $in_parenthesis->whereIn('acl.group_id',function($where_in) use($user_id){
                            $where_in->select('group_id')
                                ->from('user_group_junction')
                                ->where('user_id','=',$user_id);
                            })
                    ->orWhere('acl.user_id','=',$user_id);
                })
                ->count();

    if($acl_count < 1){
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}else{
    return Redirect::to('/');
}

Routes
Route::get('/','HomeController@index');

Route::get('login','AuthorizationController@loginForm');
Route::post('authenticate','HomeController@authenticate');
Route::get('logout','HomeController@logout');

Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'),function(){
Route::group(array('before'=>'user_permission'),function(){
    Route::get('protected','HomeController@protectedPage');
    Route::resource('sources', 'SourcesController');
    Route::resource('admins', 'AdminsController');
});
});
```

Comment: acl:Access Control List

Answer (score 2):

You can use `beforeFilter` inside the `__construct` method of the `AdminBaseController` like this (create a different one for admin controllers only)

```
class AdminController extends AdminBaseController {

    function __construct() {

        // Use filter on all methods but not on create
        $this->beforeFilter('admin', array('except' => array('create')));

    }

}
```

Also, you may directly use this `beforeFilter` inside your `resource` controller and use `except` or you can use `only` (only works reverse of except, allows access to all but filters only mentioned methods in the array). You can also check conditions inside the constructor method s well.

Comment: But from this anyone could use the create method.

Comment: Yes, you are right and if you don't want anyone to access this then you can change it, remove it from the `except`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that part of my problem is with the filter. I am only looking at the first segment of the url which doesn't work correctly if my route (whether it is a resource or just a route with a "/" in it) won't work. Thus I asked another question located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507622/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-a-route-is-a-resource-route-in-laravel-4)